# Serial programming in Arduino, reading decimal numbers with values outside of the values of 0-9

Tags: serial-port, int, arduino, communication, long-integer

I'm currently trying to use my [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) for controlling stepper motors. The task that's been assigned to me is to create a program that can control the motors, but by prompting the user to input the number of steps of displacement desired. My biggest problem right now is having the serial monitor to read these numbers as one number.

For example, I am able to use the `Serial.read()` function to read numbers and save them as int data types, but that's only for numbers from 0-9.

If I were to type in "500", the monitor would display:

```
5
0
0
```

As if they are separate numbers...

How can I input large numbers through serial communication and have them as usable int or long data types?

Comment: Can you post the code that is not working as expected?

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's done by using a sequence of characters that confirm the end of data. Most popular is... a line feed (what gets send, when you press enter - in hexadecimal it's `0x0D0A`).

So your Ardiuno needs to read from the serial port until it encounters bytes `0D0A`. Then it knows that whatever was received before, should be converted to a integer and used as the value to control your servo.